# How can I remove downloaded video file after merging video and audio?

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I downloaded 1080p video from youtube using youtube-dl. Video file (.f137.mp4) and audio files (f140.m4a) were downloaded. Them ffmpeg merged the video file and the audio file to mp4 file(.mp4). I want to keep the .f140.m4a file and the .mp4 file, while remove the f137.mp4 file. How can I do?

I tried the --exec option in the youtube-dl, but it failed.

These were my commands:

```
root@OMV:~/youtube-dl# cat dl-test.sh
DL_DIR="/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007"
ALBUM="Test"
mkdir -p "$DL_DIR/$ALBUM"
youtube-dl --batch-file  /root/youtube-dl/url-test.list --download-archive /root/youtube-dl/archive-test.list                           \
-f  'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/bestvideo+bestaudio'                                 \
--write-sub --embed-sub --all-subs                                                              \
--embed-thumbnail --add-metadata                                                                \
-o "$DL_DIR/$ALBUM/%(title)s.%(ext)s"                                                           \
--exec "rm "$(ls {} | cut -d . -f1)""
```

The result were:

```
root@OMV:~/youtube-dl# ./dl-test.sh
ls: cannot access '{}': No such file or directory
...
[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test/UpTown Spot.mp4"
...
[atomicparsley] Adding thumbnail to "/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test/UpTown Spot.mp4"
[exec] Executing command: rm  '/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test/UpTown Spot.mp4'
```

The .mp4 file was deleted, the .f137.mp4 file was still there. I got the opposite result.

```
root@OMV:~/youtube-dl# ls '/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test'
UpTown Spot.f137.mp4  UpTown Spot.f140.m4a
```

**Update 1:**
I changed to

```
--exec "rm "$(ls {} -1 | sed -n '/\.f[0-9]*\.mp4$/p')""
```

It still remove the .mp4 file. The output was:

```
root@OMV:~/youtube-dl# echo "" > "/root/youtube-dl/archive-test.list"
root@OMV:~/youtube-dl# ./dl-test.sh
ls: cannot access '{}': No such file or directory
...
[download] /srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test/UpTown Spot.mp4 has already been downloaded and merged
...
[exec] Executing command: rm  '/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test/UpTown Spot.mp4'
```

Then changed it into:

```
--exec "rm "$(ls -1 | sed -n '/\.f[0-9]*\.mp4$/p')""
```

The ouput was almost the same:

```
root@OMV:~/youtube-dl# ./dl-test.sh
...
[exec] Executing command: rm  '/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test/UpTown Spot.mp4'
```

I tested the normal expression in SHELL, it worked:

```
root@OMV:~/youtube-dl# cd /srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test
root@OMV:/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test# ls "$(ls  /srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test | sed -n '/\.f[0-9]*\.mp4$/p')"
UpTown Spot.f137.mp4
root@OMV:/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test# rm "$(ls  /srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test | sed -n '/\.f[0-9]*\.mp4$/p')"
```

But the similar command running in the youtube-dl --exec option failed!

**Update 2:**
It seemed that the cmd after pipeline would not be executed.

```
root@OMV:~/youtube-dl# ./dl-test.sh
+ DL_DIR=/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007
+ ALBUM=Test
+ mkdir -p /srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test
+ youtube-dl --batch-file /root/youtube-dl/url-test.list --download-archive /root/youtube-dl/archive-test.list -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/bestvideo+bestaudio' --write-sub --embed-sub --all-subs --embed-thumbnail --add-metadata -o '/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test/%(title)s.%(ext)s' --exec 'ls | grep mp4'
...
[exec] Executing command: ls | grep mp4 '/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test/UpTown Spot.mp4'
Binary file /srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00007/Test/UpTown Spot.mp4 matches
ls: write error: Broken pipe
```

Comment: add a shebang to your script and enable debug, e.g. `#!/bin/bash -x` then run your script again and look at the output. And as a sidenote, parsing the output of ls is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

change

```
$(ls {} | cut -d . -f1)
```

to

```
$(ls -1 {} | sed -n '/\.f[0-9]*\.mp4$/p')
```

explanation

```
ls -1      # print every file in one line

sed -n     # suppress automatic output
'/\.       # pattern start with .
f          # followed by f
[0-9]*     # some numbers
\.mp4$     # and .mp4
/p'        # print line
```

Comment: Still not work. I tested the similar normal expression in SHELL, it worked. But in youtube-dl --exec , it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a hook scripts.
Here is my dl.sh:

```
root@OMV:~/youtube-dl# cat dl.sh
#!/bin/bash

DL_DIR="$1"
ALBUM="$2"
SAVE_DIR="$DL_DIR/$ALBUM"
WORK_DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f "$0"))
URL_LIST="$WORK_DIR/url.list"
ARCHIVE_LIST="$WORK_DIR/archive.list"
HOOK="$WORK_DIR/hook.sh"

if      [ ! -n "$DL_DIR" ] ||[ ! -n "$ALBUM" ];
then
        echo "Usage: $0 <download_dir> <album_name>"
        exit 1
fi

mkdir -p "$SAVE_DIR"
youtube-dl --batch-file  $URL_LIST --download-archive $ARCHIVE_LIST            \
-f  'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/bestvideo+bestaudio'                \
--write-sub --embed-sub --all-subs                                             \
--embed-thumbnail --add-metadata                                               \
-o "$SAVE_DIR/%(title)s.%(ext)s"                                               \
--exec $HOOK
```

And this is my hook.sh:

```
root@OMV:~/youtube-dl# cat hook.sh
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"
file_full_name=$(readlink -f "$file" -n)
dir=$(dirname "$file_full_name")
file_rm=$(ls "$dir" | sed -n '/\.f[0-9]*\.mp4$/p')
#echo "file to be removed = $file_rm"
rm -i "$dir/$file_rm"
```

Thank everyone for your hints!